# Jitter on object falling down on PC and android both

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, lag, jitter, collider

I have done everything to fall a gameobject fall from top like Piano Tiles but there is always like little glitch or lag no matter what both on PC and android. I have used all combination like:

1. I used only 2d collider and move object downwards.
2. [I used rigid body with iskinematic set to true and interpolate
   selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxKFM.png)

But it always lag though fps shown on phone is mostly 55 - 57.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Unity Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html)? That can help you determine whether the problem lies in inefficient code execution, or elsewhere.

Comment: yes i have it has spikes at physics2d dont know why..

Comment: What does your scene look like, how complex is it? How about your code that you're using to move the object? Without more information, it's just guesswork at this point.

Comment: I make tile fall from top of screen these were my approaches:
1 I put a BoxCollider2d and use transfrom.trasnlate to move down the tile and at the end of screen I have and other collider with rigidbidy2d oon it to trigger for some animation and move back to pool.
2 I put Boxcollider2d and rigidbody2d on the tile because i read on many forums thats its not good to move static collider so i use rigidbody.velocity to move tile in FixedUpdate.

Comment: Was there jitter with both approaches? And a collider isn't static unless you marked it as such in the top right corner of the properties. If only one of the approaches results in the jitter, please include all relevant code.

Comment: have made it static no result same jitter.